# npm installing module url ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy peerDependencies

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

Every time I am doing **npm** install or similar on my project I am getting this..

> npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
>   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-watch@0.5.3 wants grunt@~0.4.0
>   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-coveralls@0.3.0 wants grunt@~0.4.2
>   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-concat@0.3.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
>   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-jscs@0.8.1 wants grunt@~0.4.2
>   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-qunit-istanbul@0.5.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
>   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-search@0.1.6 wants grunt@~0.4.1
>   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-jshint@0.10.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0

I have tried in different machine and with different versions of nodejs and npm

On my code, I just put require(url) which is a really basic module of node. I suppose it needs grunt in any way. I saw there is info about this error in the web but I couldn't get a solution and I have no idea how to solve it.

Anyway, this is my package.json...

```
 "dependencies": {
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "http": "0.0.0"
  }
```

It should be there 'url' as well, but it is failing exactly when I am doing

```
  npm install url --save --dev
```

Linux Mint.

Thanks, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Show us your package.json

Comment: It is really basic..I am doing some basic examples of nodejs just to learn  ....                                                                                        "dependencies": {
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "http": "0.0.0"
  }                                                                                                                more npm install url --save --dev ...it is failing with url